# Cross browser issue with line breaks: Display text from ajax call in textarea

Tags: css

This text-file has got line breaks: [image: original text]

For display the text in the textarea I use the following style:

```
textarea.journalctl{ 
     width:       640px; 
     height:      620px; 
     white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Chrome works fine and display the text exactly like in the original file. The wraps are only at the end of line. Scroll is active in x and y.

Chrome textarea: [image]

Firefox textarea in one line: [image]

**How to make them act the same? Only wrap after line break in the textfile??**

Comment: Your screenshots don't match your CSS, by the way.

Comment: Oh, this has nothing to do with AJAX. Static HTML also looks different in both browsers with `white-space:nowrap`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ofhegfpu/2/). Let's see what I can do. (Note, IE agrees with FF here.)

Comment: Hm, I can't seem to make them act the same... In Chrome, `white-space:nowrap` acts the way you want. In the other two browsers, you need `white-space:pre`. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ofhegfpu/6/). So, that's incompatible. Sorry.

Comment: @MrLister : The `width: 640px;` is edited for better reading. Also yes ajax is only an information, where this problem occurs.

Comment: Is there a way to make different rules, depending on the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One rather hackish solution is to use the `-moz-` version of the `@document` rule. Since only Mozilla recognises things starting with `-moz-`, you can use it to write CSS for Mozilla only.

```css
textarea {
  width: 16em; height: 4em;
  display: block;
}

/* for all browsers */
#ta1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Mozilla only: use for all URLs prefixed with '' (that is, all urls) */
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  #ta1 {
    white-space: pre;
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ta1">Line one is very long but shouldn't wrap
line two</textarea>
```

This solution is volatile though. Since vendor prefixes like `-moz-` are meant to be temporary, I have no idea how long this will keep working.

Then there's IE. It used to be you could target IE specifically by writing a *conditional comment*.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
  #ta1 {
    white-space:pre;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

However, that is no longer the case (since IE10). So I'm not sure there's a solution for IE, other than resorting to JavaScript to add or remove style blocks dynamically.

Comment: This solution is not elegant, but probably best by now. Thank you.